Kafka JDBC connect loading different tables per record name. Possible?
When Kafka is using the recordname subject name strategy, one topic can have different schemas. No problem for the consumer if using the proper settings.
But the goal is to load different tables per record name, e.g. the record with SALES_ORDER as name goes to the SALES_ORDER table, the record with SHIPPMENT to the SHIPPMENT table.
From what I have seen, the JDBC connector allows to specify the table name based on the topic but not the schema. Is this statement correct?

It should be possible, but you may need to fork the code to override the default logic that uses the topic name.
The naming strategy is specific to the Confluent registry, whereas the Connect API is generic, so you'll lose any such data by the time the record is destructed into columns and DDL, i.e. post Converter
Alternatively, you could use Kafka Streams / ksqlDB / Flink to split the topic into its constituents and run connect with a topic regex pattern for types you're expecting
